# Equivalent definitions of the signature of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

I'm trying to convince myself that the following two definitions of the signature of a symmetric matrix are the same. The first one says it is the triple $(p,n,z)$ where $p$ is the number of $1$'s, $n$ is the number of $-1$'s, and $z$ is the number of $0$'s in the normal form of the symmetric matrix. The other definition says it is the triple $(p,n,z)$ where $p$, $n$, and $z$ are the number of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues of the matrix, respectively.

My first guess was that this is obvious, since the diagonal elements of the matrix $P^tAP$, where $A$ is a given symmetric matrix, which is the normal form of $A$, are the eigenvalues. But now I doubt whether it is true, because this is certainly true for $P^{-1}AP$, however, the source I use does not claim that the matrix $P$ which reduces $A$ to the normal form must be orthogonal.

Comment: For square matrices, I believe this is just the spectral theorem.

Comment: @fireballs As far as I understand, the spectral theorem says that any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable via an orthogonal matrix. But the diagonal form need not be normal (the one with $\pm 1, 0$ on the diagonal).

Comment: For non-diagonalizable matrices, the eigendecomposition generalizes to the (Jordan) normal form. For diagonalizable matrices, I believe these are the same.

Comment: What is "the source I use" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia   Wikipedia do not make this aspect clear, but it makes no difference whether we stop once we have achieved $P^T HP = D$ diagonal or continue on to $D_1$ with all diagonal entries $1,-1,0.$ In $D,$ we take the count of positive diagonal entries, negative diagonal entries, and zero diagonal entries. We count exactly the same thing for $D_1$

Answer (score 1):

This same issue comes up over and over and over and over and over again. For symmetric matrices over the reals, the equivalence relation that preserves all the signs, as in Sylvester's Law of Inertia, is **congruence**. If $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric, it means there is an invertible matrix $Q$ such that
$$ Q^T A Q = B.  $$

Give me an example symmetric matrix $H$ with integer coefficients, I will put here how to solve $P^T HP = D$ diagonal. For this problem, all integers, we can arrange that $P$ has all rational entries, which means $D$ does as well, and $\det P = \pm 1.$ The diagonal entries of $D$ will not be the eigenvalues (which could very well be irrational)

Here is an example with really, really ugly eigenvalues:
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Having reached this diagonal matrix $D,$ we can continue to get only $0,1,-1$ on the diagonal by taking $R^T P^T H P R,$ where

$$
R = R^T =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt8} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &    \frac{ \sqrt 8 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ \sqrt {143} }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ \sqrt {143} }{ \sqrt {569} }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ D_0 = H $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
4 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 5 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 5 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 127 }{ 8 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 127 }{ 8 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 41 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 463 }{ 25 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. (In particular, I don't understand why you consider integer and rational entries.) Yes, the relation is congruence, and yes for any symmetric $A$ there is an orthogonal $P$ s.t. $P^tAP$ is diagonal. But this doesn't mean that the diagonal entries of $P^tAP$ are $\pm 1, 0$. (If this were true, then by the orthogonality of $P$, we'd have $P^{-1}AP=P^tAP$, and we know that for $P^{-1}AP$ the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues, so the two definitions of the signature are the same.)

Comment: @user419669 my $P$ or $Q$ is really not orthogonal. I notice from your comment that you want to arrange $0,1,-1$ on the diagonal. You can do that by starting with congruence diagonalization, $P^T H P = D$ diagonal. For each nonzero diagonal entry, now take diagonal matrix $R$ where the entry corresponding to $d_i$ is $1 / \sqrt {d_i}.$ I was not sure what you meant by normal form, this is not standard. I guess it is standard for certain applied linear algebra classes. Strange, your other questions are on the pure side

Comment: @user419669 should say $1/\sqrt {|d_i|}.$ Then $R = R^T$ and $R^T P^T H P R$ is daigonal with all $0,1,-1$ on the diagonal.